# Networkx(Python): connected_double_edge_swap losing weights after swaps, how to swap edges and keep weights (or other attributes) using networkx

Tags: networkx

if the edges are weighted, then after swaps, weights will be losing. How to swap edges and keep weights (or other attribure) efficiently using networkx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a good way for networkx to know in advance what you want the weights of the new edges to be.  Should they be the average of the old weights (and what if they are something like color which can't be averaged?)?  Should the old attributes be randomly distributed to the new edges?

It's going to depend on what you want the result to be.  Your best option is to look at the source code for the double edge swap, and then create your own function that does the same thing, but assigns the edge attributes the way you want them to be.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I may not think clearly before, I think old attributes be randomly distributed to the new edges is good for me.

Comment: Acctually , connected double edge swap means u--v, x--y to u--x, v--y. So it is better to swap weights at the same time when swap edges.